# Upload request to GCS via signed url fails apparently due to header mismatch due to apparent case sensitivity

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, fetch-api

I am trying to use a signed url to upload a file to my Google Cloud Storage.  The code to create the signed url is this:

```
    // args have name of file and type
    // config has information about the bucket, etc
    const uploadOptions = {
        destination: args.name,
    };
    console.log(`Content-Type: ${args.fileType}`)
    const signingOptions = {
        version: "v4",
        action: "write",
        expires: Date.now() + 15*60*1000,
        contentType: args.fileType,
    };

    const response = Promise.await(myStorage.bucket(config.bucketName).file(args.name, uploadOptions).getSignedUrl(signingOptions));
    return response;
```

I then use this url to try to upload the file with *fetch* thus:

```
                // writeUrl is the url created by the above code
                fetch(writeUrl, 
                    {method: "PUT", 
                    origin: "https:localhost:3000",
                    headers: {"content-type": fileElement.files[0].type},
                    body: fileElement.files[0]})
                .then((response) => {
                    // Do something 
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
```

This fails.  The url returns an error message from the server that looks like this:

```
<Error>
  <Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code>
  <Message>Invalid argument.</Message>
  <Details>Your request has a malformed header. Header was included in signedheaders, 
    but not in the request.</Details>
  <ParameterName>content-type</ParameterName>
</Error>
```

This appears to be telling me I did not include a header "content-type".  But I did, see above.  Looking at the network tab in Chrome, I see that the header is "Content-Type".  I am suspicious that case-sensitivity has showed up here.  Am I correct about this?

One complication is that Chrome's network says its description of the request headers is "provisional" I have caching turned off, which is one reason for this.  The other reason is "the url is invalid".  Maybe because it returned an error?

I am vexed that I cannot find a way to keep *fetch* from changing "content-type" to "Content-Type".  Is there a workaround for this?

What is, in fact, wrong here?  How can I get it to work?

EDIT:

Here are the headers of the request as shown by the Chrome Network tab:

```
Content-Type: image/png
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "macOS"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you share the full headers for the failing request? Header names are case insensitive (and even lose their 'case' when submitted via HTTP/2), so I doubt this is a mistake Google would make.

Comment: It seems implausible to me, too, @Evert, but I'm at a loss for any other explanation.

Comment: `+ 15*60*1000,` why not just use a number?

Comment: Because this tells me where the number came from, and that number of milliseconds is actually 15 minutes.  My memory is overworked, and the less stuff I have to remember, the better.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what's going on here.  It was my mistake.  I misinterpreted some things that the browser  was telling me, and I thought I would share my error because it might help someone else at some point.

What I was seeing was a failure of a CORS preflight request.  This was due to a misconfiguration of the CORS response on my server.

However, when I looked in Chrome's Network tab, it does not show me the preflight request at all.  So I wasn't aware that it was happening let alone looking at it to see what was wrong.

And then, not knowing this, I clicked on the link in the Chrome console that corresponded to the (signed) URL I was trying to PUT to.  This got a response that didn't depend on CORS, it seems.  It also didn't add the "content-type" header, because I just clicked on a link.  So that's why that error showed up.

So, in the end, I was doing two different things and thinking they were the same thing.  Confusion abouts.

With that insight, I fixed the CORS misconfiguration and it works now.